# How to access an items subfolders in MS Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am brand new to the Graph Explorer and am having difficulty with the syntax for file exploration. I am able to access the parent of the child directory that I want to manage data for, but I can't seem to actually access the child. I can get it listed as a child of the parent, but am struggling making the call to get into the folder. My request to the parent works fine:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
```

and listing all the children works fine. I can see my next subfolder in the response with the id and everything:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children
```

Its the next step that I am struggling with. Setting the GET call to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/{next-item-id}
```

doesn't seem to work. The response specifically reads

```
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {...
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the id of the subfolder (`next-item-id`), then use the `next-item-id` instead of `item-id`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{next-item-id}
```

Get items in the selected subfolder

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{next-item-id}/children
```

Similar for all children inside your subfolder(s), you need only these two endpoints

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{next-...-next-item-id}
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{next-...-next-item-id}/children
```

Comment: Okay, I was under the assumption I required the full directory path. But just referencing the sub folder id was enough and the parent folder id was not required. I appreciate that, I never would have intuitively tried that!